Community Promotion Ads — 2020
You lost your “beta” label in 2019, so welcome to your very first edition of Community Promotion Ads, for the year of 2020!
What are Community Promotion Ads?
Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.
Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?
This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

relevant linguistic blogs and websites
events, conferences, or meetups for Chinese language scholarship
anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about the stuff your community deems important. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are relevant to your own community's interests, both for those already in the community and those yet to join. 
Why do we reset the ads every year?
Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.
The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.
How does it work?
The answers you post to this question must conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored. 

All answers should be in the exact form of:
[![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

   [1]: http://image-url
   [2]: http://clickthrough-url 

Please do not add anything else to the body of the post. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
The question must always be tagged with the magic community-ads tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

Image requirements

The image that you create must be 300 x 250 pixels, or double that if high DPI.
Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
Must be GIF or PNG
No animated GIFs
Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB
If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.

Score Threshold
There is a minimum score threshold an answer must meet (currently 6) before it will be shown on the main site.
You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats here.

I request ones for the Chinese Grammar Wiki and Hacking Chinese.  Oh and Pleco and CC-EDICT.  Also possible is Du Chinese and Fourth Tone.  Okay, who doesn't completely suck at making these things?

Do we want one for Japanese.SE?

Relevant Meta.SE post: How can the required number of votes for community promotion ads be lowered on smaller sites?.



I attempted to whip up one for Pleco (although I'm quite the amateur).  [And perhaps there may be some copyright issues here (but other websites seem to use Pleco's logos without problems).]

You could ask on the Pleco forums (https://plecoforums.com/); I'm sure Mike would answer fairly quickly.

Okay, I did so: https://www.plecoforums.com/threads/interested-in-adding-a-community-ad-to-chinese-stack-exchange.6482/  ("Awaiting approval before being displayed publicly.")  It seems I messed up, and linked to this irrelevant image by mistake, and I can't figure out how to edit.

(I fixed the dimensions---I got them the wrong way around.)

By the way, Pleco seems interested in whipping one up.  So I expect this will be replaced by whatever they come up with.



The English version of Wiktionary has more content and is generally more valuable than the Chinese one, even for Chinese character/word lookup - I suggest changing it to en.wiktionary.org instead.

That's right! I let you guys decide :-)

I don't have a strong opinion on this, but that seems like a fair argument to change it to the English one.  (:





Sourced from the this Japanese.SE ad.

This post is for 2020, so it is not currently active.

Thanks.  I know, I'm just saving it for future reference.
